# How to send mails with mime module only for specific modules?

Tags: webforms, emails

### **Fixed it, see answer below**

On my drupal installation there are some fancy webforms which send plain text emails, turning on the mime module messes them all up. But, I need the mime module to send html mails when using simplenews newsletters.

I did the following in the settings but it has no effect (html = plain):
[image]
(http://abload.de/img/bildschirmfoto2013-11w1j7v.png)

What did I miss? How to use the mime mails only when simplenews is sending mails? I set HTML as format in newsletter settings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I installed the HTML Mail module and created a new setting with Mail >> Simplenews leaving the key blank, which works fine now!